# Adding Favorite Rows of UITableView to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I am programing an iOS app which is almost completed, I've added a Favorite Button to UITableView, it works pretty well, on press it changes its image.

Here is my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"maincell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    Categories * CategoryObject;

    CategoryObject = [categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = CategoryObject.categoryTitle;

    self.tableView.allowsSelection = YES;

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
//  Adding Button



    UIButton *addtoFavsButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     if([[myFavorites objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row]]){
    [addtoFavsButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}else{
    [addtoFavsButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}    
    addtoFavsButton.frame = CGRectMake(300.0f, 0.0f, 105.0f, 45.0f);

    [cell addSubview:addtoFavsButton];
    [addtoFavsButton addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(addtoFavs:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:addtoFavsButton];
    [addtoFavsButton setTag:indexPath.row];





 // Configure the cell Image...

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:CategoryObject.categoryImage];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    UIImage *placeholderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"];
    __weak UITableViewCell *weakCell = cell;
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:placeholderImage success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
        weakCell.imageView.image = image;
        [weakCell setNeedsLayout];
    } failure:nil];


    return cell;

}


- (IBAction)addtoFavs: (id)sender
{

  //  UIButton *button = sender;
    UIButton *addtoFavsButton = sender;

    NSLog(@"selected favourite button tag %li", (long)addtoFavsButton.tag);

    myFavorites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if (addtoFavsButton.selected) {
        [addtoFavsButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                 // Needs code Help here to Remove object from myFavourites array which is similar to addtoFavsButton.tag
    }
    else{

        [addtoFavsButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

             // Needs Code Help here to add addtoFavsButton.tag to myFavorites array's index path.row
    }
    addtoFavsButton.selected=!addtoFavsButton.selected;


     }
```

and here is picture of my app

[image]

above code is working well, but what I am wanting to accomplish is

1. Add number from  `myFavsButton.tag`  to `indexpath.row` of `NSMutableArray` called `myFavorites`
2. If number already exists in `myFavourites` array then remove it.

both of the points are in `- (IBAction)addtoFavs: (id)sender`

I also have to discuss about the best approach because my data is Cached, which I am displaying in TableView, Since I am making rows Favorite in my app because I've to display those favorite rows in another viewcontroller Table View, so please advice me whether this method is best suitable to call for data to server again & again to display selected(favorite rows) only. like this in new vewcontroller

```
if([[myFavorites objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row]]){
     // Is a favorite, so put regular cell stuff here to have the cell show
     ....

 }else{
     // Not a favorite, don't generate cell.
     cell.visible = NO;
     return cell;
 }
```

or yet there's some better solution to not to make call for same data to the server again & again, and to copy multiple Favorite Rows's Objects like as `textlable` & `UIImage` and to display those Favorite rows in another `viewcontroller`'s tableview?

Comment: In your addToFavs function, why are you creating a new myFavorites array?

Comment: Because I wants to add button pressed cell's reference number in that myFavorites Array & I'll further use this array in my second viewcontroller to display only those number of rows which containing this myFavorite Array

Comment: But see you are using `myFavorites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

It will create a new array. You should write that line in viewDidLoad and simply use `[myFavorites addObject:object]` if it doesn't exist, otherwise `[myFavorites removeObject:object]`. Basically everytime you click the button, a new empty array will be created and thus losing all previous objects you may have added into it.

Comment: I tried that approach while writing that in `viewDidLoad` method but as you see I've also used same `myFavorites` Array in above `cellforRowAtIndex` method. hence if by writing that in viewDidLoad method it gives error in program execution. 
I know how to add something in an array, but in my case if I write '[myFavorites addObject: addtoFavsButton.tag] ' it gives error write in coding window.

Comment: The compiler throws an error because you can only add objects. And tag is a NSInteger. You need to convert it to a NSNumber object. You can do something like: 
`[myFavorites addObject:@(addToFavsButton.tag)]` This will create a NSNumber object and you'll be able to add it to the array.

If you have declared myFavorites as a global array, and then initialized it in `viewDidLoad`. I don't see why it would throw an error. But as far as I can tell in your approach, everytime you click a favourites button, you will have an empty array and it will always contain one object.

Comment: OK that works now when I converted it to NSNumber Object. but still I needs little bit more help. coz app is not saving state. 
If you see disclosure indicator button in above my app's image that is for showing specific cell when I tap on that it displays image of relevant cell in another detail view controller, & when I comes back now it is giving me same state i.e with favorite button clicked. but when I reload my app no favorite button is clicked. I mean `myFavourites` array is not storing proper data when I reload the app... any Idea?

Comment: By reload you mean completely kill the app and then start it again?

Comment: One thing more, as I tried to comment those lines `[myFavorites addObject:@(addToFavsButton.tag)]`  and `[myFavorites removeObject:@(addToFavsButton.tag)]` it still showing same functionality if i go forward to another detail view controller & comes back same result as without commenting those lines.

Comment: yes. by reload app completely restarts
Actually currently I've 3 view Controllers, in very first viewController data is being fetched from external Json server, when user clicks on any row, it brings user to another(this concerned) ViewController with another Tableview that also fetching another set of Data from Json API,  now when I move forward to its detail View Controller it showing me detailed image, & when I comes back it also showing me saved cells, but when I further move back to very first view controller or terminates the app in both cases saved cells becomes unsaved automatically

Comment: Thats cause your object that is acting as a dataSource for your tableView is getting deallocated from memory. If you want data persistance you can either use Sqlite, NSUserDefaults or CoreData. You should have a look at some tutorials for each and decide which is the best approach for you!

Comment: when I tried to put `myFavorites =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` in `viewDidLoad`method, it giving me following error 

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'`

So I removed that initialization from `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: I've to only save `myFavorites` NSMutable Array's Data & I already visited those tutorials, so according to me NSUserDefaults will be the best approach, because I am not using Sqlite as data source & my data is being fetched from Json API so I've to only save reference to button clicked arrays I mean saved arrays reference & when displaying Json API Data I'll filter that if Json Arry's Number already exists in myFavourites NSUserDefault array or not, if yes then I'll display button as clicked, & if not then button without clicked. 
But I don't know how to use NSUserDefaults.

Comment: The crash in `viewDidLoad` is because (hopefully) your `cellForRow` gets called as soon as view loads but your array has not been populated yet with data and you are calling `objectAtIndex` but there is no such index. A quick fix for this would be to check in `numberOfRowsForSection` if the size of the array is more than 0, then only you should return the number, otherwise return 0. And reload your table as soon as you get the data. 

Kindly look at some tutorials for NSUserDefaults (and debugging if i may add).

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your help